# MSIL - how opcode conv.ovf.u8.un work?

Tags: c#, cil

Why `msil` program:

```
.assembly Test {}
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       21 (0x15)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 a,
           [1] int32 b)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.m1
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloc.0
  IL_0005:  conv.ovf.u8.un
  IL_0006:  stloc.1
  IL_0007:  ldloc.1
  IL_0008:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(uint64)
  IL_000d:  nop
  IL_000e:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey()
  IL_0013:  pop
  IL_0014:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

write output: `-1`?

`conv.ovf.u8.un` - convert unsigned to an unsigned int64 (on the stack as int64)
and throw an exception on overflow.

So `-1` (int32) treated as unsigned is `4294967295` (uint32) and it treated as uint64 is `18446744073709551615`.

Ecma documentation says: http://postimg.org/image/4326dsysx/

So again `-1` (int32) in binary is
`111111111111111111111111111111111`.
After conversion by zero extending it is
`000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111`
and it is again `18446744073709551615`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it and on my system it did not print -1 but 18446744073709551615.
Could you provide more information about your system (platform, .NET / CLR version) or just try to build the executable again with `ilasm`?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I updated whole system, rebooted and now it's working correct. It is very interesting because before that I have problem with other opcodes e.g. `conv.ovf.u8` and now everything is okey.

Thank for tips!